# Hover effect for only one element and not effect the other divs with same class

Tags: jquery, toggle, jquery-hover

This is probably an easy one but I'm a little lost it's been a long day. Anyway I have a sprinkle of divs each a different size and for every different size it has it's own class.

```
<div class="LARGE">
    <div class="Content"></div>
    <div class="HOVER_CONTENT"></div>
</div>

<div class="SMALL">
    <div class="Content"></div>
    <div class="HOVER_CONTENT"></div>
</div>

<div class="LARGE">
    <div class="Content"></div>
    <div class="HOVER_CONTENT"></div>
</div>

<div class="MEDIUM">
    <div class="Content"></div>
    <div class="HOVER_CONTENT"></div>
</div>
```

On hover i'm looking to first toggle a class of ACTIVE. On active i'm removing CONTENT via CSS and displaying HOVER CONTENT as block.

```
<div class="LARGE ACTIVE">
    <div class="Content"></div>
    <div class="HOVER_CONTENT"></div>
</div>
```

Problem that I'm having is if I hover over the second LARGE the HOVER CONTENT displays on the first LARGE. I only want that to display on the LARGE div that I hovered over.

```
$('.HOVER_CONTENT').hide();

$('.LARGE').hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.HOVER_CONTENT').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just need context:

```
$('.LARGE').hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.HOVER_CONTENT', this).toggle(); //adds context
});
```

or:

```
$('.LARGE').hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').find('.HOVER_CONTENT').toggle();
});
```

capital letters are not needed, and is just bad form IMO.

Comment: I did have one more question. If I wanted to check the div if hover_content is present if so then toggle hover_content if not then don't. Thanks again!

Comment: The answer sort of does that, as nothing will be toggled unless find finds a hover_content element.